# Not able to delete plain literals from virtuoso using jena

Tags: java, jena, virtuoso

I am having a little problem deleting untyped literals from Virtuoso using the Jena API.

Consider the following graph as an example:

```
s   p                                          o
a   http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label "label1"
b   http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label "label2"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string>
```

Resource `a` was added through the Virtuoso SPARQL query editor.

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
WITH <testgraph>
INSERT DATA { <a> rdfs:label "label1" }
```

Resource `b` was added by using the Jena API.

```
DatasetAccessor dsa = DatasetAccessorFactory.create(new VirtDataset("localhost:1111", "dba", "dba"));
Model m = dsa.getModel("testgraph");
m.createResource("b").addProperty(RDFS.label, "label2");
```

I have tried to delete the triples by using `removeProperties()` --

```
Model m = dsa.getModel(GRAPH);
Resource a = m.createResource("a");
Resource b = m.createResource("b");
a.removeProperties();
b.removeProperties();
```

-- and by executing a SPARQL query via `UpdateAction` --

```
UpdateAction.parseExecute("DELETE { ?s ?p ?o } WHERE { ?s ?p ?o . FILTER (?s = <a> || ?s = <b>) }", m);
```

-- but in both cases, only resource `b` gets removed. Reason is the untyped literal of resource `a` - when I explicitly add the `xsd:string` type to `label1` then resource `a` gets deleted as well.

Are there any settings I am missing for Jena or Virtuoso on how to handle these untyped literals?

I'm using Jena 3.4.0, Virtuoso 7.2.4.2, `virt_jena-3`, and `virtjdbc-4`.

Comment: Am I correct in thinking that executing the same SPARQL query directly through the SPARQL endpoint successfully deletes these triples? Please note that `virt_jena-3` and `virtjdbc-4` each have their own version; [it's important these be current](http://vos.openlinksw.com/owiki/wiki/VOS/VirtJenaProvider#Prerequisites). Check them with `java -jar ./virt_jena3.jar` and `java -cp ./virtjdbc4.jar virtuoso.jdbc4.Driver` (adjusting the paths for your local environment). The build-date (or code snapshot date) of the Virtuoso server may also be relevant.

Comment: yes you are correct
```OpenLink Virtuoso(TM) Provider for Jena(TM) Version 3.0.0 [Build 1.25]```

```OpenLink Virtuoso(TM) Driver for JDBC(TM) Version 4.0 [Build 3.100]```

that should be the latest ones

Comment: i updated the jdbc driver to ```OpenLink Virtuoso(TM) Driver for JDBC(TM) Version 4.2 [Build 3.96]``` but the behavior is still the same.. for the jena provider i was not able to find a more recent version

Comment: Note that the "Version" in those strings is about JDBC (JDBC 4.2 == Java 8; JDBC 4.0 == Java 6), so you've actually *down-dated* the driver, from `v3.100` to `3.96`. Given everything you've said, I *think* the issue lies in Jena. Logging every layer will be the best way to confirm my thinking, and to move the analysis forward.

Comment: Jena 3.4.0 provides RDF1.1  - "abc" is shorthand for "abc"^^xsd:string. Is the Virtuoso store RDF 1.0? The result set suggests it is. As you add/delete for `b` consistently via the Jena API, the b-label is consistenetly ^^xsd:string.  But `a` is added by sending a SPARQL Update to Virtuoso so it may produce the RDF 1.0 string without datatype then which means it may be missed by RDF 1.1 handling code.